# Hiding paraphyletic objects in CSS

Tags: css, userscripts

I'm trying to style elements of a webpage over which I do not have control (think userscript). I have a chunk of HTML like so:

```
<dt>
  <a href="..." class="important-link">important text</a>
  Long unimportant text that doesn't matter to me.
  <a href="..." class="unimportant-link">this doesn't matter either</a>
</dt>
```

How can I hide everything in the `dt` except the important link? I would like to set display to none, but once the `dt` is undisplayed it can't redisplay its children. I don't merely want to set the text to `visibility:invisible` since it is long (the whole point is to cut down on scrolling).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the font size in the `dt` to `0` (to hide the text node), hide the `.unimportant-link`, and then re-set the font size on the `.important-link` (to override the `0` font size it would otherwise inherit).

```
dt {
    font-size: 0;
}

dt .unimportant-link {
    display: none;
}

dt .important-link {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

You could alternatively use `visibility: hidden;` if you want the space taken up by `.unimportant-link` to stay (rather than removing it from flow via `display: none;`).

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5QZPr/)**

Answer (score 1):

Based on the fact that you have a text node with no wrapping element, there's only one approach that I see which could work. You'd need to set the height of the `dt` to be equal to the font size of your `.important-link`.

```
dt{
  height: 1em;
  overflow:hidden;
  }
dt .important-link{
    font-size: 1em;
    display:block;
}
```

This effectively sets that first link as "block level", and then "cuts off" all of the remaining text. If you wanted to undo this later in the session, you could set `height: auto`, remove `overflow:hidden`, or both.

Answer (score 0):

If you try it:

```
dt * {
    display: none;
}

dt *.important-link {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: The (very long) text isn't in a containing element so this doesn't hide it.

Comment: note that visibility: hidden will still reserve space for the hidden object. Using display:none will not reserve space. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone

Comment: @Charles if you want to hide the text, you need to wrap it into something then. div, p, etc. Otherwise, the only way to hide it is to hide the entire dt.

Comment: @teabos: As I said in the question, I do not have control over the HTML, only the CSS.

Comment: @teabos Not necessarily, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20685651/1883647).